# How to display php alert message in html using sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert

this is my contact form.
I need to display message in sweetalert after `success/fail` submission of form. The error/success message is in php alert.

```html
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="post" id="form_id">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No." required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Id" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Travel Date" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" style="height:140px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="send">SEND MESSAGE</button>
</form>
```

This is my `php` code

- for send mail

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$alert = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $package=$_POST['package'];
  $date=$_POST['date'];

  try{
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = ''; // Gmail address which you want to use as SMTP server
    $mail->Password = ''; // Gmail address Password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = '587';

    $mail->setFrom(''); // Gmail address which you used as SMTP server
    $mail->addAddress(''); // Email address where you want to receive emails (you can use any of your gmail address including the gmail address which you used as SMTP server)

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Message Received';
    $mail->Body = "<h3>Name : $name <br><br>Phone No: $number <br><br> Country: $country <br><br> Email: $email <br><br>Arrival Date: $date <br><br>Package: $package <br><br> Message: $message</h3>";

    $mail->send();
    $alert = 'alert-success';
  } catch (Exception $e){
    $alert = 'alert-error';
  }     
}
```

this is my `javascript` code

- swal alert
- is `alert-success` check

```js
success:function(alert) {
    if(alert == 'alert-success'){
        swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
    }
    else swal("Something is missing!!!!!", "Try again","error");
}
```

Comment: are you sending form submit using ajax ?

Comment: No.do i need to use ajax to send  form?

Comment: I am receving mail but i need to display alert message after completion

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

if not using ajax you can do this :

```
 <script>
 var alert = '<?php echo $alert;?>';        
 if(alert == 'alert-success'){
     alert('yes');//for test 
      swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
 }
 else if(alert=='alert-error'){
       alert('no');//for test
       swal("Something is missing!!!!!", "Try again","error");
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: Nop..nothing happen but i am receving mail

Comment: you have to put the php script in the same file you have the form. and secondly i updated the question and added alert may be swal() throwing some error kindly check you console for error .

Comment: I have <?php include 'sendemail.php'; ?> in a file

Comment: that will work too. now just check your console if its throwing some error . or try printing your <?php echo 'test'.$alert;?> to check what it contains for debugging . before the java script

Comment: <?php echo 'test'.$alert;?> ----showing the "alert-success" message

Comment: did you check you console ??

Comment: yes i got "alert-sucess" message..but i need this message in popup

Comment: hope that this js  script is in you current  page ???

Comment: can you share your response screenshot ?

Comment: cuz i dont understand when u get the "alert-success" message then it should got the the if condition define in js and then should produce an alert and swal alert

Answer (score 0):

you should have to be use ajax for this sweet alert operation.

```js
$.ajax({
  .... other settings you already have
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    swal("success!", "Form has been submitted", "success");
  }
});
```